# git seems not to want to push a folder?

Tags: git

git has been working like a charm until this small problem.

I have copied a Spanish locale folder into my local directory structure but git seems not to want to push it to my repo?

These are the commands I used:

```
git checkout dev
```

(moved folder into place)

```
git add .
git commit -m 'message'
git checkout master
git merge dev
git push *** --all
```

These work for all other files ?

Any idea how I can rewind and push again easily?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The ANSWER (just in case) This git work flow worked fine for me. I had not flushed the Cache on the server so it seemed as if the files were not uploaded, when in fact they had been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ANSWER (just in case) This git work flow worked fine for me. I had not flushed the Cache on the server so it seemed as if the files were not uploaded, when in fact they had been.

Answer (score 3):

Are there any files in the folder? If not, that's why it doesn't push it to the repo.

Comment: The folder has a lot of files, yes.

Comment: Sorry guys, over sight on my part - I forgot to clear the cache!!! Result of too many eye ball hours...

Comment: @squeaker, please consider posting your answer then, and accepting it: it's a perfectly legal SO practice.

Answer (score 2):

As Alex D.

but If you really need the "empty" folder then you should add a .gitignore file to the folder. this will allow the folder to be added to the repository as the folder is no longer empty

Comment: Good point about adding a file... but normally people use a file called `.gitkeep`, not `.gitignore`. `.gitignore` goes in the root directory of the repo, and specifies which files should be "ignored" by git.

Comment: It is a matter of religion : ) I have been using .gitignore as it a documented feature misused, where .gitkeep is not documented in the git help.

But .gitignore does not necessarily have to be put in the root, i have several places in our software stack where we want to ignore specific files in one directory, but not in another. 

Also adding the .gitignore to specific directories allows you to move directories without affecting the root .gitignore file.

Comment: OK, very well! I've never seen directory-specific `.gitignore` files before, that's a good tip!